# Function that receives a char and returns the square power of it's integer value

Tags: function, char, integer

I need to create a function that transmits a parameter as a 'char' and returns the value of that 'char' as a integer at its square value.
For example:

```
char nr[] = "11";
cout << strToNumber(nr);//will return the value 121;
```

```
int strToNumber (char c[]) {
int cifra, rezultat, fin;
cifra = c - '0';
return cifra * cifra;
}

int main () {

char sir[9] = "13";
char c;

int n = strlen(sir);
  for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
   c = sir[i];
    strToNumber(c);
  }
return 0;
}
```

I tried to send the whole 'char' as a parameter one at a time. First I sent sir[0] which is '1' and afterwards I sent sir[1] which is '3'. The problem is that I did not manage to save the parameters in one variable so that I can easily multiply it by itself. In this case each parameter is multiplied by itself one at a time. '1' * '1' and '3' * '3'.
I am new to this 'char' and I do not fully understand it yet. If there is another way to send my parameters and to handle the function I would truly appreciate it... Thanks in advance!